# searchFiles() Does not find description from files in Google Drive uploaded via Google Form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-forms

I have a script set up in a Google Form that changes the description of the file based on the form's answer, that one works perfectly. However, I have another script that uses Driveapp's searchFile function to search the file's descriptions using the fullText query, this is able to find the files no problem based on the title, but not the description.

The way I have it set up, I have a function that receives the folder ID and the query as parameters, and then calls the searchFile function like so:

`fileList = DriveApp.getFolderById(id).searchFiles("fullText contains '" + query + "'");`

Again, this finds the files in the folder based on the title no problem, but not the description. However I did some testing and found the following:

- Uploading a file manually and giving it the same description works perfectly, they show up in the search no problem.
- Using the same function but without tying it to a folder also works perfectly, like this:

`fileList = DriveApp.searchFiles("fullText contains '" + query + "'");`

I'm guessing it has something to do with permissions, but I have no idea what to tweak.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your issue of `this is able to find the files no problem based on the title, but not the description.`. When I prepare 2 sample files by giving a description by both manual operation and a script, those files can be retrieved by `fileList = DriveApp.getFolderById(id).searchFiles("fullText contains '" + query + "'")`. So, I'm worried that I misunderstood your question. So, can I ask you about the detailed flow for correctly replicating your issue? First, I would like to correctly understand your issue.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply, I was able to come up with a fix (copying the files via script)

To go into more detail: This seems to only not work with files uploaded directly via a Google Form, how the description is made doesn't seem to affect it.

So for example: File "A" gets uploaded to the drive normally via a google form, then the desciption is set. After that, when trying to search it up, it does not show up.

Then, I upload the same file directly into the drive and give it the same description, then that file is able to show up in the search.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. I cannot understand `So for example: File "A" gets uploaded to the drive normally via a google form, then the desciption is set.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: Sorry, stack overflow doesn't notify me about replies, but the step by step is:

1) Make a google form that allows users to upload files.
2) Upload a file through the google form.
3) Change the description of the file uploaded, either manually or with a script that does it.
Expected: File shows up using searchFiles()
Reality: File does not show up using searchFiles()